# Изменение текста label for для вложенного input типа checkbox

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, как изменить текст label (15 человек) с помощью jQuery (например, 220 человек):

```
<label class="class_label" for="check1"><span class="class_span"></span><input type="checkbox" id="check1"/>15 Человек</label>
```

Так меняется не только текст, но и затирается span:
    $(".class_label").text('220 человек');

Comment: Так нужно:

$(".class_label")[0].lastChild.nodeValue = "220 человек";

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ:

```
$(".class_label").html('<span class="class_span"></span><input type="checkbox" id="check1" />220 человек');
```

А, вообще, лучше текстовое значение обернуть в `span`. Будет что-то типа:

```
<label class="class_label" for="check1">
    <span class="class_span"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
    <span class="label_caption">15 Человек</span>
</label>
```

Тогда можно так:

```
$(".class_label .label_caption").text('220 человек');
```

Comment: Если еще учесть наличие чекбокса с id="check1" - это будет хорошее решение :)

Comment: Да, согласен. А еще не мешало бы разметку перестроить. Тег `<label>` не должен оборачивать `<input>`.

Comment: Согласен. А если совсем не парить мозг, просто выводить надо все блоки с одним номером

    <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" />
    <span class="label_caption" id="count-check-1">15 Человек</span>

и проблем вообще не будет.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше:    <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" />    <label id="count-check-1" for="check-1">15 Человек</label>И `<label>` свою функциональность выполняет и тегов меньше :)

Comment: Конечно, первое, что пытался - добавил span с id, но летит вся верстка, а она сложная и уже менять не можно(

Решение с заменой всех внутренностей label, тоже не катит, это я для простоты так пример оформил, там конструкция сложнее, и переписывать все - не есть гуд.

Вопрос именно в использовании jQuery механизмов. Если это возможно, конечно.

Comment: Можно попробовать читать свойство `.html()`, регулярным выражением искать число, менять и записывать обратно. Но это будет еще тот костыль и он усложнит код и аукнется в будущем! Все же, лучше, переверстать.

Answer (score 1):

А я даже в ответ вынесу =)

```
$('.class_label').has('#check1').find('.label_caption').text('220 человек');
```

Comment: Я уже выше написал, что этот способ не подходит.

Answer (score -1):

Вынеси "span" за label:

```
<span class="class_span"></span>
<label class="class_label" for="check1">
 <input type="checkbox" id="check1"/>15 Человек
</label>
```